# Trigger to Truncate then Insert rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, truncate

Everyday, some rows will be inserted into a SQL Server Table (T_PAST). These rows will be records from the past (ie August 1, 2013) as well as records that are in the future (ie January 1, 2014). I want to leave the past dated records in the table (T_PAST), but for the future date records, I would like to:
1) Delete them from the original table
2) Insert them into a new table which only has future dated records (T_FUTURE)

The thing is, the future dated records can have changes in the columns, so instead of running an update query as well, I would prefer to truncate the T_FUTURE table, and reinsert the records.

Everything works in the sense that the proper records are insert into T_PAST, the proper records are delete from T_PAST and the T_FUTURE table is truncated. My problem is that when I insert multiple future dated records, only the last record shows in the T_FUTURE table, not all of them.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_GetFuture]
ON [dbo].[T_PAST]
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.T_FUTURE
END

BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.T_FUTURE
SELECT *
FROM INSERTED
WHERE DATE > GETDATE()
END

BEGIN
DELETE FROM dbo.T_PAST
WHERE DATE > GETDATE()
END
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Where do you insert into `T_FUTURE`? Tip: You may want to add `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` near the beginning of the procedure and use `@Now` thereafter. Otherwise you have an opportunity for some hard to find timing bugs as the values of `GetDate()` changes from the `INSERT` to the `DELETE`.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo - it now shows where I insert into T_FUTURE. Also, thanks for the heads up on the declare.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are truncating the T_FUTURE table in the trigger. 
Every time trigger is fired it will first truncate the T_FUTURE table and then will insert a new records to this table.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as well. I thought the trigger will fire only after all rows have been inserted, so it would only truncate once, then add all of them, but that is not the case I guess. Any idea as to how to fix this?